# Select most recent inspection

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, greatest-n-per-group, date

I have a `ROAD_INSPECTION` table:

```
+----+------------------------+-----------+
| ID |          DATE          | CONDITION |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | 01/01/2009             |        20 |
|  1 | 05/01/2013             |        16 |
|  1 | 04/29/2016 10:02:52 AM |        15 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
|  2 | 01/01/2009             |         8 |
|  2 | 06/06/2012 9:55:13 AM  |         8 |
|  2 | 04/28/2015             |        11 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
|  3 | 06/11/2012             |        10 |
|  3 | 04/21/2015             |        19 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
```

---

What is the most efficient way to select the most recent inspection? The query would need to include the `CONDITION` column, despite the fact that it wouldn't `group by` cleanly:

```
+----+------------------------+-----------+
| ID |          DATE          | CONDITION |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | 04/29/2016 10:02:52 AM |        15 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
|  2 | 04/28/2015             |        11 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
|  3 | 04/21/2015             |        19 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
```

---

For bonus points: The `DATE` column has both DATE and DATE_TIME values in it. Should I be worried about this causing complications when querying the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX( "DATE" ) AS "DATE",
       MAX( CONDITION ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY "DATE" ) AS condition
FROM   road_inspection
GROUP BY id
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT r.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE" DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   road_inspection r
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

> The `DATE` column has both `DATE` and `DATE_TIME` values in it. Should I be worried about this causing complications when querying the column?

Oracle has no concept of a `DATE_TIME` data type. There is only `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` and both of them have a `HH24:MI:SS` time component (`TIMESTAMP` also has fractional seconds). If a `DATE` value is set without a time component then oracle will default to midnight (`00:00:00`) of that day for the time component of the date.

Assuming your `DATE` column is actually stored as a `DATE` data type (and not as a `VARCHAR2`) then, no, there will not be any complications (with regards to selecting the rows with maximum values) from having time components as all your values will have a time component.

Comment: Why is it necessary for the `WHERE` clause to be in a subselect?

Comment: @Wilson Yes, if you try putting the `ROW_NUMBER()` expression into the `WHERE` clause you will get `ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here`.

Comment: Would Oracle 12c's `FETCH FIRST` functionality be a third option?

Comment: @Wilson No - that will just fetch a certain number of rows from the entire result set - not a certain number of rows for each partition of the result set.

Comment: Fair point. ypercube's answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/188586/100880) might be of interest, although he figures it's not much of an improvement on `row_number` .

Answer (score 2):

The  following gives you the most recent record per id

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT a.* ,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date DESC) rn
   FROM USER1.ROAD_INSPECTION a
)a
WHERE a.rn =1;
```

I'm not sure what you mean by complications when querying column of type `DATE`. `2010-01-01` is the same as midnight of Jan 1, 2010.

***Update***. Fixed missed `FROM` clause.

Comment: The only complication that I can think of would be around trying to filter on a date range. An end user might try to filter with 04/29/2016 as the end date and could be expecting ID 1 to appear.

Comment: Is there a typo in the aliases too (`rn`, `a`)?

Comment: @Wilson : no, not a typo.  maybe not the best style, but perfectly valid syntax. Table alias `a`  and inline view alias `a` can be used this way without any conflict.